# Android draw app

Tags: java, android, graphics, opengl-es, libgdx

I am making simple game in Android. Main functionality is to draw path with brush so that path will stay after next graphics update. Im trying to use LibGDX currently. If I used ShapeRenderer I would have to remember all point and overlaying would be a problem. So I draw on Pixmap and then Pixmap on Texture. The graphics result is ok but I get laggs and low fps on slower devices.

Can you help me with this problem or suggest some Android framework which simple "drawing on canvas" will not be a problem.

Comment: Are you initializing your shape renderer in every frame? Or just once?

Comment: When I use ShapeRenderer I initialize it in constructor and only draw in update method. But this is not this problem because there are a problem with overlap more colors. Actually I used something like this: in constuctor I initialize Pixmap and Texture; in update method I set color and fill circle on pixmap, draw pixmap on texture and draw texture on batch;  This procedure results one path.

Comment: Why are you creating your pixmap in the update method